How to disable multiple network accounts of the Google drive on Fedora Budgie 41
Recently I updated Fedora Budgie from 39 to 41.
In the 39 version, the network accounts based on Google Drive were possible to have.
In the Fedora 41 budgie, this feature was cut and is not possible for traditional 'Online Accounts' of the system to disable it.
After the upgrade, I have notifications that are not possible to synchronize the accounts of Google Drive. The message is:
Failed to sign in to multiple accounts.
I am not able to find where these accounts are placed in the current Fedora Budgie 41 to delete them.
